# Can't start VM OpenNebula

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cluster, high-availability, opennebula

I have 3 nodes with **CephRBD** + **OpenNebula** + **Corosync** + **Pacemaker** + **Galera** + **crmsh**.

Software: **OpenNebula 4.14.2**, **CentOS 7.1**

All works, but when I instantiate VM, a get an error and VM in PENDING status:

```
No system datastore meets capacity and SCHED_DS_REQUIREMENTS: CLUSTER_ID = 100 & !(PUBLIC_CLOUD = YES)
```

I found this report: [CephRBD is for Images.](http://lists.opennebula.org/pipermail/users-opennebula.org/2013-November/042987.html)

VM TEMPLATE

```
CONTEXT=[NETWORK="YES",SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="$USER[SSH_PUBLIC_KEY]"]
CPU="1"
DISK=[IMAGE="CentOS",IMAGE_UNAME="oneadmin",READONLY="yes"]
DISK=[IMAGE="VM_Image",IMAGE_UNAME="oneadmin"]
FEATURES=[ACPI="yes"]
GRAPHICS=[LISTEN="0.0.0.0",TYPE="VNC"]
HYPERVISOR="kvm"
LOGO="images/logos/centos.png"
MEMORY="512"
NIC=[NETWORK="Management",NETWORK_UNAME="oneadmin"]
OS=[BOOT="cdrom"]
SCHED_REQUIREMENTS="CLUSTER_ID=\"100\""
```

I have another single host without clustering, and there are no this problems.
OpenNebula 4.12.2

Where do I have a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Each cluster needs to have (at least) a system DS. That scheduler message means that either your cluster 100 does not have a system DS, or the system DS found does not have enough capacity for the pending VM.

If there is a system DS in that cluster, it may not be properly monitored, showing a storage capacity of 0.

Comment: So, I must have a shared system DS at all nodes too?

Comment: Not necessarily shared, it can be ssh. See: http://docs.opennebula.org/4.14/administration/storage/ceph_ds.html#configuring-the-system-datastore

Comment: Suppose there was a failure and the host poweroff. The data will not be replicated to another host? My task is to make the system fault tolerant. Can I use any alternatives? With minimal points of failure.